# Set the length of textxboxes with the class = "txt" to width = "200"

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, textbox

I am trying to set the length of textxboxes with the class = "txt" to width = "200"

I tried it on JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wr04fdm3/ but it gave me an off the wall answer.

```
<asp:TextBox Class="txt" ID="txtone" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Class="txt" ID="txttwo" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox Class="txt" ID="txtthree" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            $(".txt").each(function () {
                $(this).val().width = 200;
            )};
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You can't copy-and-paste asp.net markup code directly into jsfiddle. You're missing the step where the asp.net server code converts this into html as part of the request processing

Comment: do you want to change text box width only after button click or at all times, if width should be 200 all times the better approach is using CSS style sheets. If you want to change width after button click try any of the below answers

Comment: Also, your fiddle uses asp text box instead of a normal text box, asp textboxes does not work in JS fiddle

Answer (score 2):

Change your script to this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $(".txt").width(200);
    });
});
```

There were a couple of things wrong with it.  First of all, no need to use `each()` for something like this.  It will automatically parse all the selected elements for you.  Secondly, `width = 200` was wrong.  As you can see above it should be `width(200)`.

Finally, it wouldn't work on jsfiddle because it doesn't parse ASP.Net.  You'd also not selected to include jquery.  Here's an updated working version of your fiddle...

**http://jsfiddle.net/ArchersFiddle/wr04fdm3/4/**

Answer (score 0):

you can use css method in jquery to set styles to elements

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        $(".txt").css("width","200px");
    });
});
```